# how can i add user input in to the empty string in def?

Tags: python

```
def user_names_animal():
        a = ''
        b = ''
        a = input('enter the name of animal a : ')
        b = input('enter the name of animal b : ')
        return (a,b)


def concu(a,b):
    if a[0] == b[0] :
        print('the first letter {} is the same'.format(a[0]))
    else :
        print('the first letter {} is the same'.format(a[0]))




enter = user_names_animal()
co = concu('a','b')
concu(enter,co)
```

'NoneType' object is not subscriptable this is a errot that i get when it reach this part of code  if a[0] == b[0] : and it says obj is none type i want to slove question and the q is :
Write a function takes a two-word string and returns True if both words begin with same letter
i dont know the problem is and i cant fix it

Comment: `concu` returns None. You are calling `concu(enter, None)` in your last line.

Comment: For starters, `'a','b'` is not a two word string, they are two *arguments*. A two word string would be such that: `'two words'`.

Comment: `a, b = user_names_animal()` `concu(a, b)`.

Comment: You dont need `co = concu('a','b')`, which returns None and mess with your result, just call `concu(*enter)` in order to evaluate the two words the user provides. By the way, your `else` condition should state that the first letter is different, but I'm guessing this is a copy paste you didnt correct yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement is for a function that takes a two-word string (presumably a string with 2 whitespace delimited tokens) that returns True if the first letters of each word are the same otherwise False.

```
def get_words():
  a = input('Enter first word: ')
  b = input('Enter second word: ')
  return a, b

def concu(s):
  word1, word2 = s.split()
  return word1[0] == word2[0]

a, b = get_words()

if concu(f'{a} {b}'):
  print(f'First letter {a[0]} is the same')
else:
  print(f'First letters {a[0]} and {b[0]} are different')
```